# Smallest $k$-regular unit-distance graph

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, extremal-graph-theory

We can create arbitrary $k$-regular unit-distance graphs by using a "hyper-cube construction": taking a $k-1$-regular unit-distance graph, making a copy and translating it one unit distance that is not parallel to any of the existing edges, and connecting all vertices between the two copies ([source](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132763/maximal-minimum-degree-of-unit-distance-finite-graphs)).

However this is not optimal, considering in the $k=2$ case using our construction we get a rhombus looking graph while the complete graph $K_3$ is optimal. The 3-cube graph has 8 vertices while a triangular-prism looking graph has 6 vertices. What are the smallest $k$-regular unit-distance graphs?

My idea that the $k=3$ six vertex case is optimal: the four vertex case is the complete graph which is not a unit-distance graph, and the five vertex case cannot satisfy the handshaking lemma.

Answer (score 3):

For 4, you need Generalized Quadrangle {2,1} on 9 points.

For 5, Shift and copy GQ21 for 18 points.
A smaller quintic unit distance graph might be the Clebsch graph, but that can likely be proven to not be unit distance.

At 6 you get Hamming-{3,3}  (27 points)
[image: Hamming 3,3]

Comment: Do you know these are optimal?

Comment: Yes, these are optimal.

Comment: Do you have a proof or reference?

Comment: Nope, just a large database of graphs and a lot of work on unit distance graphs.  I'm the one that found Hamming 33, for example.

Comment: Note: Hamming $(3,3)$ is **not** rigid. Jorge Mireles's 36-edge "solution" to the braced nonagon is invalid, being a subgraph of Hamming $(3,3)$. Khodulyov's solution remains the best.

Answer (score 2):

What space are you in?  If you are in $\Bbb R^{k-1}$ or higher, you can use a regular simplex.  That is clearly minimal.

Comment: the plane (I think this is standard for unit-distance graphs)